# Gunicorn worker terminated due to signal 10

Tags: gunicorn, logrotate, uvicorn

```
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [885694] [INFO] Handling signal: usr1
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [886183] [INFO] Handling signal: usr1
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [886183] [WARNING] Worker with pid 887296 was terminated due to signal 10
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [886183] [WARNING] Worker with pid 887293 was terminated due to signal 10
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [886183] [WARNING] Worker with pid 887300 was terminated due to signal 10
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [886183] [WARNING] Worker with pid 887298 was terminated due to signal 10
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [885694] [WARNING] Worker with pid 887294 was terminated due to signal 10
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [885694] [WARNING] Worker with pid 887299 was terminated due to signal 10
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [887306] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 887306
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [887307] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 887307
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [885694] [WARNING] Worker with pid 887297 was terminated due to signal 10
[2022-07-07 00:00:19 +0900] [885694] [WARNING] Worker with pid 887292 was terminated due to signal 10
```

Hello,

I have gunicorn with worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker.
It is set up with logrotate.

However,
I see that the worker is terminated and booted again due to USR1 (10) signal,
which is odd.

Because when I look at gunicorn implementation, all it seems doing (and should be doing) is reloading the log file!

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/cf55d2cec277f220ebd605989ce78ad1bb553c46/gunicorn/workers/base.py#L181

```
def handle_usr1(self, sig, frame):
    self.log.reopen_files()

def init_signals(self):
    # reset signaling
    for s in self.SIGNALS:
        signal.signal(s, signal.SIG_DFL)

    # init new signaling 
    signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, self.handle_quit)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.handle_exit)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.handle_quit)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGWINCH, self.handle_winch)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, self.handle_usr1)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, self.handle_abort)

    # Don't let SIGTERM and SIGUSR1 disturb active requests
    # by interrupting system calls
    signal.siginterrupt(signal.SIGUSR1, False)
```

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/60d0474a6f5604597180f435a6a03b016783885b/gunicorn/glogging.py#L357

```
def reopen_files(self):
    if self.cfg.capture_output and self.cfg.errorlog != "-":
        for stream in sys.stdout, sys.stderr:
            stream.flush()

        with self.lock:
            if self.logfile is not None:
                self.logfile.close()
            self.logfile = open(self.cfg.errorlog, 'a+')
            os.dup2(self.logfile.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
            os.dup2(self.logfile.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())

    for log in loggers():
        for handler in log.handlers:
            if isinstance(handler, logging.FileHandler):
                handler.acquire()
                try:
                    if handler.stream:
                        handler.close()
                        handler.stream = handler._open()
                finally:
                    handler.release()
```

Why is it killing my processes (and it does not even terminate them gracefully - it kills them while these workers are running)? Any idea with be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I remember we may have had issues on signals and logrotate specifically, see https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/896, would you open a discussion on uvicorn repo with a minimal way to reproduce ?

Comment: The above code is from base worker.py, but arbiter.py has `self.kill_workers(signal.SIGUSR1)` https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/027f04b4b4aee4f50b980a7158add0feaf4c1b29/gunicorn/arbiter.py#L293

This code is the one actually called when USR1 signal is issued by logrotate. (Which is odd?)

We worked around the issue by setting `signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signal.SIG_IGN)`.

Comment: You are right -  on more digging the issue is to do with uvicorn worker not implementing signal handler - https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/291c195c65940d33025d91778758f06924f34bfd/uvicorn/workers.py#L68. It converts it to signal.SIG_DFL. 

SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 both have the default action Term -- the process is terminated. (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/why-does-sigusr1-cause-process-to-be-terminated) I can see from the link below by changing those line to gunicorn worker's init_signals, the worker no longer restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/pull/1565

This was a uvicorn worker bug.